# Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Personal Info Data Type - Phone number

Tags: android, wear-os, google-play-console

When I add the wearable dependency to my Android app and upload it to the Play Store, my app is rejected due to invalid data safety (Phone Number).

Screenshot

[image: 1]

I have checked Manifest Merge (build/outputs/logs) and there are no permissions for READ_CALL_LOG, READ_PHONE_NUMBERS, READ_PHONE_STATE, READ_SMS.

Also, when I try to remove the dependencies.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:18.0.0'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.6.4'
```

And uploading it on Play Store, my app update is approved.

Do we have to add Phone Number in Data Safety to support Wearable?

**EDIT :**
Finally found out where is the issue. It's caused by the outdated of some libraries.
The build.gradle files don't show any warning. We have to go to Build > Edit Libraries and Dependencies > Suggestion.

Comment: I also started seeing this (phone number) violation today.  I made a minor change to an app (not WearOS) and upgraded a few android libraries at the same time.   I'll downgrade the libraries and resubmit to see if that clears the violation.

Comment: Follow up: I downgrading the libraries and resubmitted.  The app went live without issues. No violations found.

Comment: @Java42 I summited a new update, and it got rejected again. Which library did you downgrade?

Comment: Here are the downgraded libraries and versions:    'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.2'
'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.3'
'androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:7.3.1'
'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.2'
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.4.0'

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue but the culprit was...

'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'

I went back to

'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.2.0'

and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this warning is the usage of
Google Mobile Ads (GMA) SDK. https://play.google.com/sdks/details/com-google-android-gms-play-services-ads